# Why do we leyn before mincha but after shacharis?

Tags: shabbat, torah-reading, fast-days, mincha-afternoon-prayer

When reading Torah in the morning, we daven shemoneh esrei of shacharit and then afterwards read the Torah.

When reading Torah in the afternoon (Shabbos/fast days), we read Torah first and then daven shemoneh esrei afterwards.

Why the difference in ordering?

Comment: And after maariv and before musaf

Comment: @Heshy when do we lain after maariv?

Comment: @aBochur Simchas Torah.  And Purim and Tisha Beav if you count megillos.

Comment: @heshy oh i didn't know that, as in chabad we dont lain on simchas tora after maariv.

Comment: Smichas ge'ula l'tefilla?

Comment: @rosends it could have been after yishtabach.  That's basically where it is in mincha.

Comment: @Heshy but there is a sof zman for K"SHm and the amida. Delaying them might be a problem. OTOH there is also a zman for mincha...

Comment: Maybe it's so that people who had to work could leave early from Shacharit and come late to Mincha

Comment: @rosends If you consider *semichat Ge'ulah Letefilla* for Ma'ariv, there isn't really a choice other than place laining after the *Amidah*. Incidentally, there is a debate as to whether *semichut* is necessary for Ma'ariv.

Answer (score 11):

This question was asked on [kipa.co.il](http://www.kipa.co.il/%D7%A9%D7%90%D7%9C-%D7%90%D7%AA-%D7%94%D7%A8%D7%91/%D7%A7%D7%A8%D7%99%D7%90%D7%94-%D7%91%D7%AA%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%94-%D7%95%D7%AA%D7%A4%D7%99%D7%9C%D7%AA-%D7%A2%D7%9E%D7%99%D7%93%D7%94/).

The answer given by R. Ronen Lebovitz was:

> וזאת משום שבשחרית יש לסמוך את קריאת שמע לעמידה, ולכן קריאת התורה באה רק לאחר העמידה. טעם נוסף הוא שהתפילות תוקנו כנגד קורבנות התמיד. בשחרית לא היה דבר הקודם לתמיד של שחר, ואילו במנחה לא היה נעשה דבר לאחר תמיד של בין הערביים, ולכן אין קוראים בתורה לפני תפילת השחר, ולא אחרי תפילת המנחה
>
> This is because at *shacharit* one needs to have *keriat shema* immediately followed  by *amidah*, therefore the *keriat hatorah* only comes after *amidah*. A further reason is that our [*amidah*] prayers were established to correspond to the daily offerings. At *shacharit* time, nothing came before the daily morning offering, whereas at *minchah* time, nothing was done after the daily afternoon offering. Therefore we do not read the Torah before *shacharit* [*amidah*], nor after *minchah* [*amidah*].

Comment: As I mentioned in the comments to the question, I don't understand the first answer.  Just do it after yishtabach.

Comment: I think an important piece is missing from the explanation. Do we assume that specifically the *Amidah* is what is the substitute for the sacrifices? I **think** that's what's going on, but the answer doesn't specify this. Perhaps, you want to clarify that aspect, esp. for many readers who don't know this/

Comment: "Sidepoint" - In Shacharit, why do we have *Tachanun* between the Amidah and reading? Assuming my previous comment, why not place Torah reading immediately after Amidah?

Comment: @DanF I’ve edited to clarify in line with your first comment. In terms of your second comment, tachanun is seen is as being an addendum to amidah (e.g. see Rambam [here](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Mishneh_Torah,_Prayer_and_the_Priestly_Blessing.5.13?with=all&lang=he)) so it wouldn’t make much sense to interpose keriat hatorah between them.

Comment: @DanF as a further proof on the Tachanun point, there is the Gemara in Bava Metzia about Rabbi Eliezer praying for the death of Rabban Gamliel and its effectiveness based on connecting Shmona Esrei & Tachanun

Comment: @Heshy https://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=1281&st=&pgnum=68 shema is deorayta

Comment: @Heshy we cant interrupt betweeen yishtabach and shma

Comment: @Yaakov you can for communal needs, which this would seem to qualify as

Comment: @DoubleAA it says in the instructions to tehillas hashem siddur by the alter erbbe not to read along during that time in an aliya, could be others have diff customs but without a source i wouldnt assume

Comment: @Yaakov5777 The source is Shulchan Arukh OC 54:3

Comment: @DoubleAA "e.g., to levy charitable donations for someone who comes and asks for alms. Similarly, if a sheliach tzibbur did not have a tallis and/or tefillin and they were brought to him between Yishtabach and Kaddish, he may put them on, with their respective blessing[s]. If, however, they were brought to him before Yishtabach, he should recite the blessing[s] over them before Yishtabach, as stated in sec. 53[:3].9
" no mention of reading along, thats an assumption https://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/3285920/jewish/Shulchan-Aruch-Chapter-54-Laws-Relating-to-Blessing-Yishtabach.htm