# When is the earliest time one could read the haftarah on Shabbat?

Tags: shabbat, shacharis-morning-prayer, haftarah

I was thinking about the seven weeks of consolation and how we read the seven prophecies of Yeshaya. So, naturally I wondered if it were possible to read the haftarah portion seven hours into Shabbat (provided the vetikin minyan could finish Shacharit in time)?

Comment: Your definition of "naturally" is very different from mine. Even now in the summer, 7 hours after starting Shabbat doesn't take you to a point where you can say Shacharit.

Comment: @magicker maybe in the far north

Comment: Is this meant to be a generic question about the laws of reading the haftarah or a specific question about a practice of aligning this haftarah with a "seven" for thematic sake?

Comment: Generic. If Shabbat starts at shkia and one got permission to start davening at alot hashachar, when is the soonest time that the haftarah could be read?

Comment: So are you asking a question that would depend on the precise location or about the halacha of when one can say certain things (https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/28789/krias-hatorah-or-megillah-before-davening)

Answer (score 2):

Near Manchester UK, myzmanim.com tells me that for Shabbos Parshas Bolok,

Sunset Fri night was:   9:42:16. (7 hours later is 4:42:16 Shabbos morning.)

Earliest time for talis & tefillin was  2:50:55 and sunrise was 4:41:33.

During the winter we often daven shacharis from the earliest time for talis & tefillin. So if you could accept to say the shacharis Amidah before sunrise (not like the Vatikin), you could continue the order of the service and read the Torah and the Haftorah within 7 hours of Shabbos coming in.

Comment: It would work better for (1) Shabbat Pinchas, (2) Helsinki [I happened to be there once on June 21!], (3) Chabad.org has the times as 1028pm for candle lightning, 402am for neitz, so plenty of time :-> Feel free to use if you wish. https://www.chabad.org/calendar/zmanim_cdo/aid/143790/locationid/219/locationtype/1/tdate/7-2-2021/jewish/Zmanim-Halachic-Times.htm